# Hide and show multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to hide and show a `div`(jQuery `toggle()`). This is an example of my code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $("a").click(function() {
       var myelement = $(this).attr("href");
       $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
       $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide(500);    
   });
 </script>

  <h2><a href="#box1"> Programming</a></h2>

   <div id="box1" class = "block-content" style="display:none">
    box 1 
   </div>

   <h2><a href="#box2"> software</a></h2>

   <div id="box2" class = "block-content" style="display:none">
    box 2
   </div>
```

It doesn't work and Firebug doesn't show me an error message.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You're just missing a `;`

Comment: @Dan: Semicolons aren't required. The script is, however, looking for elements with the "toggle" class, of which there are none in the sample HTML.

Comment: You're missing [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: OK, well the code looks ok and works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhnq4d2k/)

Comment: What does "It does not work" mean? What are you expecting it to do, and what isn't it doing to fulfill your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xyzpq44x/

- API: `preventDefault` you want to prevent default behaviour of `a` tag http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

rest should help `:)`

**try this**

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
    $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide(500);

});
```

Comment: thank's it's working, i did a lot of stupid mistakes

Answer (score 1):

When the script runs, the a tags are not yet present on the page!

Put your script below the html elements, or use document ready or equivalent to postpone the script execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide(500);
```

replace ".toggle:visible" with "div"